# Not able to access cloud foundry auto configuration in play framework (application.conf file)

Tags: java, playframework, cloud-foundry

I have use this link https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying-CloudFoundry for auto configuration. I have done in my application.conf.

```
db.default.driver=${?cloud.services.mysql.connection.driver}
db.default.url=${?cloud.services.mysql.connection.url}
db.default.password=${?cloud.services.mysql.connection.password}
db.default.username=${?cloud.services.mysql.connection.username}
```

Its throwing an following error .
  ERR Caused by: Configuration error: Configuration error[dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.]

Answer (score 0):

This features is not yet implemented by the play framework 2.5.